# How to ignore lombok.@UtilityClass for Jacoco?

Tags: jacoco, lombok, test-coverage

I have used `lombok.@UtilityClass` to:

- generate a private constructor
- make the class final
- make all fields in the utility class static

And Jacoco does not cover Lombok generated code. If I explicitly define a private constructor, Jacoco can recognize it.

So, any way to avoid coverage penalty due to usage of `@UtilityClass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the same can be done to solve this, as what we do to ignore any Lombok generated code: add `lombok.config` file in the project root with these lines:

```
# this is root dir and don't search for parent
config.stopBubbling = true
# add @Generated and Jacoco will detect Lombok generated code and ignore them in reports
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```