# Why sonarqube shows different coverage for classes with the same .class files?

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, lombok, jacoco

I have a class with `@UtilityClass` annotation. However, if I won't set the fields as static, sonarqube complains about 0% coverage for these fields. What is interesting, `@UtilityClass` annotation automatically adds static fields when it is compiled. So basically .class files are the same for `@UtilityClass` with static or without static fields. So why sonarqube shows different results if .class files are the same...?

```
import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;

@UtilityClass
public class Test {

    public final static String TEST = "test";
}
```

This class has the same .class file after compilation as this one:

```
import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;

@UtilityClass
public class Test {

    public final String TEST = "test";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore lombok.@UtilityClass for Jacoco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272632/how-to-ignore-lombok-utilityclass-for-jacoco)

Comment: @aksappy No, this question is how to make jacoco ignore auto generated classes. I have  this configured. My question is: Why sonarqube shows different results for classes which have the same compiled content (the same .class files)?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it’s because Sonarqube’s unit test metrics as they are using a different methods to calculate the coverage. So there is no guarantee that both coverage results will be identical. You can check Sonarqube’s metrics regarding the unit tests

https://docs.sonarcloud.io/digging-deeper/metric-definitions/#tests